# Problems using i-installer on OS X

Tags: latex

I am following the instructions on the page- http://guides.macrumors.com/Installing_LaTeX_on_a_Mac
I tried setting up tex on my MBP SnowLeopard using the instructions in the section - Second (more difficult) option
However I am seeing following issue while using i-installer.
When I click - open i-package for i-Package 'gwTeX based on TeX Live, I get the following error -
Cannot read remote table of contents. The most probable cause is a download problem.

If I select the option - show i-package info, I get - appendAttributedOutput: (NULL)

So I cannot move forward in this approach. I am new to LaTex/Tex and would like to learn how to use it on mac. Any idea how I can fix this issue? It seems that i-installer is no longer supported. But the easier approach that the web site maintains involves downloading a 1.3 GB file, which is proving to be very difficult for me due to network issues (even though I have broadband).

So any help will be highly appreciated - either pointers on how to fix the i-installer issue or how to get TeX working on mac using other approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i-Installer is old, unmaintained, deprecated, and totally not something you should attempt to make work if you are new at this.

If you really can't get access to a reliable network long enough to download MacTeX, then get the MacTeX [BasicTeX distribution](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) (92M), and the MacTeX Additions package (191M), which has all the GUI apps and other utilities that aren't strictly part of the TeX distribution. If you find yourself wanting to use a package that isn't included in BasicTeX, you can use the TeX Live Utility to download and install the package. (You could even use it to get all the packages in the full distribution, but downloaded individually.)

Comment: Thanks. I will give this approach a shot and then update the thread.

Comment: I have decided to use this approach. I also tried MiKTex on Windows and it is working fine. Thanks for the reply.